# How to get multi-levels with a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child, hierarchy

I am building a multi-level referral system and I would like to offer bonuses on a pyramidal way. My simplified users table has this model:

```
id | referal
------------
1  |  Null
----------
2  |  1
----------
3  |  2
----------
4  |  2
----------
5  |  4
----------
```

I was wondering how can I get an entire pyramid just from one mySQL query: 
Example : Get all refferals pyramid starting with user 5 
Correct Answer: 5-4-2-1

I know to code this but Sql is faster!

Comment: It's not clear from your question what exactly you're trying to do. What, for instance, do you mean by "a pyramidal way"?

Comment: Have a look at Common Table Expressions and recursion - that's the way I would approach it...

Comment: I would like to do a website, so mySQL would be perfect!

Comment: MySQL is the one database that *doesn't* support CTEs and recursive queries, which is the most elegant way to do hierarchical queries. It's not the only database used for web sites either.

Comment: if you are trying to stay free but need more advance DB you might want to consider switching to [tag:PostgreSQL] which indeed supports recursive CTE http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html